# Why my merge sort doesn't ordening descending?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mergesort

I searched a lot on the site but I didn't find any solution to my problem.

I have my code here:

```
function mergeSort(arr, prop, ord){
    if(arr.length <= 1){
        return arr;
    }

    let mid = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);

    let left = mergeSort(arr.slice(0, mid), prop, ord); 
    let right = mergeSort(arr.slice(mid), prop, ord); 

    return merge(left, right, prop, ord);
}

function merge(left, right, prop, ord){
    let newArr = [];

    while(left.length && right.length){
        if(left[0][prop] < right[0][prop]){
            newArr.push(left.shift());
        }else{
            newArr.push(right.shift());
        }
    }

    if(ord === 'asc'){
        return [...newArr, ...left, ...right];
    }else if(ord === 'desc'){
        return [...newArr, ...left, ...right];
    }
}
```

and I want to ordening this array:

```
let data = [
    {
        "color": "A",
        "door": 1,
        "wheel": 3,
        "year": 1963,
        "brand": "GMC",
        "sold": false,
        "owner": "Chalmers Boobyer",
        "motor": 10,
        "assembled": "20/08/2021"
    },
    {
        "color": "B",
        "door": 2,
        "wheel": 2,
        "year": 1980,
        "brand": "Ford",
        "sold": false,
        "owner": "Angelia Cromett",
        "motor": 12,
        "assembled": "02/05/2021"
    },
    {
        "color": "C",
        "door": 3,
        "wheel": 1,
        "year": 1999,
        "brand": "Audi",
        "sold": false,
        "owner": "Barth Pickring",
        "motor": 15,
        "assembled": "15/02/2021"
    },
    {
        "color": "D",
        "door": 4,
        "wheel": 1,
        "year": 2008,
        "brand": "Hyundai",
        "sold": true,
        "owner": "Aurore Soaper",
        "motor": 11,
        "assembled": "02/01/2019"
    }
];
console.log(mergeSort(data, 'motor', 'desc'));
```

This array is a part of my dataset.

I want ordening by descending, but if I want ordening by ascendent my code works well.

Why doesn't work in descending?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your order check returns the same array for both conditions

Comment: And your comparison is always `<`

Comment: why? console.log(mergeSort(data, 'motor', 'desc')) I want 'desc'

Comment: So I want to put  a new 'if' inside my 'while' with 'asc' and 'desc'? changing the signal to '>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any condition checking when merging those arrays in the `merge` function since the order you're providing is the same.

Then, since it's either ascending or descending, the `eval()` function simplifies that bit by transforming a predefined string containing either `>` or `<` to a statement which sorts it accordingly

```js
function mergeSort(arr, prop, ord){
    if(arr.length <= 1){
        return arr;
    }

    let mid = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);

    let left = mergeSort(arr.slice(0, mid), prop, ord); 
    let right = mergeSort(arr.slice(mid), prop, ord); 

    return merge(left, right, prop, ord);
}

function merge(left, right, prop, ord){
    let newArr = [];

    while(left.length && right.length){
        let operator;
        operator = ord == "asc" ? "<" : ">"
        if(eval(`left[0][prop] ${operator} right[0][prop]`)){
            newArr.push(left.shift());
        } else {
            newArr.push(right.shift());
        }
    }
     
    return [...newArr, ...left, ...right];
}

let data = [
    {
        "color": "A",
        "door": 1,
        "wheel": 3,
        "year": 1963,
        "brand": "GMC",
        "sold": false,
        "owner": "Chalmers Boobyer",
        "motor": 10,
        "assembled": "20/08/2021"
    },
    {
        "color": "B",
        "door": 2,
        "wheel": 2,
        "year": 1980,
        "brand": "Ford",
        "sold": false,
        "owner": "Angelia Cromett",
        "motor": 12,
        "assembled": "02/05/2021"
    },
    {
        "color": "C",
        "door": 3,
        "wheel": 1,
        "year": 1999,
        "brand": "Audi",
        "sold": false,
        "owner": "Barth Pickring",
        "motor": 15,
        "assembled": "15/02/2021"
    },
    {
        "color": "D",
        "door": 4,
        "wheel": 1,
        "year": 2008,
        "brand": "Hyundai",
        "sold": true,
        "owner": "Aurore Soaper",
        "motor": 11,
        "assembled": "02/01/2019"
    }
];

console.log(mergeSort(data, 'motor', 'desc'));
```

Comment: Thank very muuuchh!!! I tried to put a variable as the operator but it didn't work.
I didn't know eval was used for that! Thank you!